# Ubuntu Server on Virtual Box - SSH only via terminal but nothing via browser

Tags: networking, server, ssh, virtualbox

I've have been using this forum for a while and it has helped me a lot.

Currently i am running Ubuntu Server 20.04 in Virtual Box with Mint 20 as Host

Virtual Box connection setup as bridge and server with static ip

From host i can "ssh server@ip" and ping my server ip via terminal.

But when i type "ssh server@ip" in my host browser just does a google search instead to redirecting to server.

I am a noob but usually been able to find my answers but now I'm stuck with this one for a couple of days and wasn't able to find any other similar query.

What am i missing?

if i can ssh from terminal makes me believe ports wise should be ok?

edit: i run firefox sandboxed so i've installed chromium and with this one the conection times out

thank you!

Comment: A web browser is not an SSH client, so this would be why a browser wouldn’t work as expected. Why are you trying to use a browser to SSH?

Comment: from this https://hibbard.eu/install-ubuntu-virtual-box/ where it says  


"or just hit DuckDuckGo.

Then (ensuring that you replace “jim” and the IP address with your corresponding values) you can connect like so:

ssh jim@192.168.178.66

This will give you a warning that the host’s authenticity cannot be established and ask you if you want to continue connecting. Answer “yes”.

Next, it will prompt you for your password. Enter it and you will be connected to your Ubuntu server from your host OS."

Comment: Perhaps it’s the late hour, but I’m not seeing anything about using SSH from a browser. Unless you have a special extension installed to handle this, a browser will not be able to do anything with SSH. Browsers typically work with ports 80 and 443 (though there are exceptions) and with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Maybe the better question is “What is it you’re trying to do in the browser that you can’t do in the terminal?”

Comment: sorry last message was incomplete 

from this https://hibbard.eu/install-ubuntu-virtual-box/ where it says  

"or just hit DuckDuckGo.

ssh jim@192.168.178.66

This will give you a warning that the host’s authenticity cannot be established and ask you if you want to continue connecting. Answer “yes”.

Next, it will prompt you for your password. Enter it and you will be connected to your Ubuntu server from your host OS."

and on my mind would be also a way to validate that the server is accessible from outside the VM.

Comment: I may have read it wrong will search about that, thank you a million Matigo for giving me more pointers for my search

Comment: If you’re just trying to test that the VM is accessible from outside, SSHing from a terminal in Mint will do that for you. So long as you can connect, you’re good 

Comment: Matigo you question “What is it you’re trying to do in the browser that you can’t do in the terminal?” made me think and with that I've setup Webmin and can access now to my server vm from my host browser so I consider this solved.

Thank you very much for helping me with this!